# Pipes executes command only once

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I'm new on StackOverflow and learning about pipes in C. I'm trying to make a shell interpeter that allows introducing 2 commands linked by pipe like

```
/bin/ls -l | /bin/grep a
```

I have a main which have a function that reads a command, then main calls a function that searchs for a "|" and if it finds it, the function makes 2 commands from it, then that function calls another one which executes the commands. My problem is that it just works once. If I introduce a command with  pipes it executes it perfectly, but if I do it again it doesn't work, like the directory had change. It doesn't matter that the first command has pipes or not, the second command (if it has pipes) wont execute correctly. I think it's because of the pipes, the code of the function that execute the pipes:

```
void execute_pipes(char *** command1, char *** command2){
pid_t son;
int tube2[2];
pipe(tube2);
son=fork();
if(son==0){//son1
    dup2(tube2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(tube2[0]);

    if(execv((*command1)[0],*command1)==-1){
        printf("Error");
        exit(0);
    }
}else{//father
    son=fork();
    if(son==0){//son2
        dup2(tube2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(tube2[1]);


        if(execv((*command2)[0],*command2)==-1){
            printf("Error");
            exit(0);
        }
    }else{//father
        close(tube2[0]);
        close(tube2[1]);
        waitpid(son, NULL, 0);


    }
}
}
```

I'm sure that the parameters are ok, ending with a NULL parameter (if not I guess it wouldnt execute one time). In each new read, a new pipe is created. I guess that the last pipe won't affect this new one but I don't know...
An example of this:

```
   /home/user/Desktop$ /bin/ls -l | /bin/grep -
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user      435 dec 18 02:33 filename
 drwxrwsr-x 9 user user     4096 dec 20 19:23 filename
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user    14464 dec 20 20:29 filename
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3580430 dec  5 03:24 filename
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     6833 dec 20 20:05 filename
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     6772 dec 20 18:48 filename
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user     1226 dec 19 21:48 filename
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user     8704 dec 18 16:23 filename
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 33673847 oct 17 20:50 filename
/home/user/Desktop$ /bin/ls -l | /bin/grep -
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 126584 feb 18  2016 /bin/ls
/home/user/Desktop$
```

NOTE: I've changed my username for 'user' and the names of the files for 'filename'.
Thanks whoever who reads this.
Summarising: my code only executes a command correctly one time, the second time it doesn't work properly and I don't know why, but I guess the problem are the pipes.

Comment: you need to hook stdout of the first to the second. I don't see that anywhere in your code

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41250027/edit) to clarify exactly what the problem is?  I can't tell.  I do see your `dup2` calls to hook the pipe to stdin/stdout.  One thought - you are only calling `waitpid` for one child.  You might try `waitpid(-1, ...` in a loop to wait for both children before the parent exits.  Not sure that would matter, but it couldn't hurt to try.  -- Separately, check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about the site!

Comment: Done, I added it at the end. I tried to wait twice, but result is the same. Thanks for the info about the tour and for answering me!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "hook stdout"? I started with pipes a few days ago and I don't have much idea, sorry.

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  The call to the function may be as important as the code in the function.  Be aware that [Three-star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not a compliment — and there is no obvious reason for using three stars in the code you show.

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler I have already solved the problem, anyway thanks for the info. Didn't know about that, I've been using C just  for 5 months or so.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, so I'm posting it as an answer. Welcome to SO. It will be easier for people to help you if you provide a working example, which I think you can. Here is a guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Unfortunately I can't get your code to work. Maybe looking at an example implementation of a lightweight shell will help you. [Here](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/sh.c) is the source code for xv6 shell. Search for PIPE keyword.

> > xv6 is a re-implementation of Dennis Ritchie's and Ken Thompson's Unix
> >     Version 6 (v6).

Comment: The problem is that I have to hand in this as homework and I'm afaraid someone could copy it. Anyway, thanks a lot for info about xv6, it looks very useful.

Comment: @YoloD.Haksel: If your code shouldn't be shown, you shouldn't be asking on SO.  All else apart, if you get an answer and then delete the question, you are going against the spirit of SO.  It would be better to delete the question now with your academic ethics unsullied than to leave it around for long enough to get an answer and then delete it.

Comment: @pbn I shouldn't show every part of it, but I guess some parts can be shown. It's late now to delete this but I'll be more careful the next time, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Oke, I solved the problem, it was a problem of the initialization of the parameters. It was in a function I didn't write because I supposed it worked.
The only doubt I have now is why was even able to execute...
Thanks everyone for  answering me .